# install Magento-Cloud cli at local question

Tags: installation, cli, magento-cloud

I am trying to install Magento-Cloud cli to my local, however I am not familiar with the server setup, I did read thru the documentation from Magento. but I don't get it work. Please help, I am not a good server guy

edit:
I just find out, I can change to root and access magento-cloud

```
sudo su
```

How can I do it for current user account? such as : paul

Thanks, I think should be changing something by below, but I don't know how.

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.magento-cloud/bin

$PATH & $HOME should be what
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile in in Linux dist probably.